# KOA POST parsing error

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm trying to get the POST data using koa-body-parser but I get the following error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
  at Object.parse (native)
```

This error refer to

/co-body/node_modules/raw-body/index.js

I think that the library co-body is trying to use "parse" but in my node version this function is restricted.

I'm using node 0.11.13

This is a part of the app.js

```
var path=require('path');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(require('koa-body-parser')());

//enrutamiento
app.use(require('./configs/routes')(app));
```

This is the function that recibe the call:

```
function *(){
    /*
    var str = 'email=lopezchr%40gmail.com&password=123123';
    console.log(JSON.parse(str));
    */
    var self = this;
    var attributes= this.request.body
    var userModel = this.models.user;
    userModel.create(this.request.body).exec(function(){
        self.body={success:true,description:"user Created"}
    });
}
```

Aditionally, when I try to do this:

```
var str = 'email=lopezchr%40gmail.com&password=123123';
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

I optain the same error..

**update**

In other post, I realized that string is not a JSON.. sooo... that is the problem...

I'm trying to do this:

```
$.post('/auth',$(form).serialize(),function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

And I want to recibe the form data with koa-body-parce...What should I do?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: If you want to send JSON, then you have to encode your data as JSON. `serialize` encodes the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you can not use that.

Answer (score 0):

For some reazon, the jquery  function $.post was sending the message with type json.. so that caused the error.. now the message type is plain/text and works.. thanks